# Adding model to an Entity

Tags: entity-framework

I'am new to EF. and my problem is I want to add the `Category` model to the Product (entity).

But it turns out that EF is Adding another Category when i add new product.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; } = true;

}

public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ROP { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EOQ { get; set; }

        public bool isActive { get; set; } = true; 
    }


            var prodcategory = gridView2.GetFocusedRow() as Category;
            context.Categories.Attach(prodcategory);
            context.Products.Add(new Product
            {
                Name = name,
                Barcode = barcode,
                Description = description,
                ROP = rop,
                EOQ = eoq,
                Category = prodcategory
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your dbcontext classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
     Products = new HashSet<Product>();
     }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; } = true;

     InverseProperty(nameof(Product.Category))]
     public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}

public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
        [InverseProperty("Categories")]
        public  virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ROP { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EOQ { get; set; }

        public bool isActive { get; set; } = true; 
    }
```

After this you can save category:

```
            var prodcategory = gridView2.GetFocusedRow() as Category;
            context.Products.Add(new Product
            {
                Name = name,
                Barcode = barcode,
                Description = description,
                ROP = rop,
                EOQ = eoq,
                Category = prodcategory
               });
             contex.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you get your category data from db?